# Getting Error using signalR with angularJS . Cannot Read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am new to signalR and angularJS. What i am doing is clients create request and i push that to a list, when the request is proceeded then i remove the request from the list and i wanna do it with signalR. But i am getting the following two errors

```
Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
```

second error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:46134/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=20WsvznP01qCy%2F7Rc7DIB42lGvhuVaX2IFyx%2B4p9enOQoWoUkIrjGMf6A7nQSo6Z7dRrI6qylIxFhQVU7t5JCftSLjwu9sDcAW8DbDOy3MTIAcA5RjZPXM19FEr1%2Fj3E&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22requesthub%22%7D%5D&tid=10' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

following is my angularJS code

```
$scope.hub = $.connection.requestHub;
    $scope.remHub = $.connection.removeHub;
    $scope.addRequest = function () {
        $scope.hub.client.addUserRequest = function (request) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.requestList.push(request);
            })
        }
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }
    $scope.removeRequest = function () {
        $scope.remHub.client.removeUserRequest = function (index) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.requestList.splice(index, 1);
            });
        }
        $.connection.remHub.start();
    };
    $scope.addRequest();
    $scope.removeRequest();
```

and i have created two different signalR classes as given below

```
[HubName("removeHub")]
    public class removeHub : Hub
    {
        //public void Hello()
        //{
        //    Clients.All.hello();
        //}
    }
```

seond class

```
 [HubName("requestHub")]
    public class requestHub : Hub
    {
        //public void Hello()
        //{
        //    Clients.All.hello();
        //}
    }
```

i have created two context for the above two hub class given below

```
requestAttr attr = new requestAttr();
            attr.ID = id;
            attr.movieName = request.movieName;
            attr.description = request.description;
            requestContext.Clients.All.addUserRequest(attr);
```

seond context

```
 removeRequestContext.Clients.All.removeUserRequest(index);
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code. Any body Please help.

P.S: If i remove removeUserRequest hub then it work perfectly fine. but i want to implement the removeUserRequest with the signalR

Comment: why do you try to start the connection multiple times? You should do this only once even if you have multiple hubs. This: ` $.connection.remHub.start();` seem incorrect. `remHub` does not have the `start` function - you need to use `hub` i.e. `$.connection.hub.start();` and as I said do not start the connection multiple times. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: yeah you r right thank u :) ... i have corrected the first error. Although its working correctly now but still i have the second problem..

Comment: This is probably on the server - it appears that something is throwing an exception on the server side and the server closes the connection.